# Unifying K2 component's data-source for multiple Joomla! websites hosted in the same server

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla-k2

I am responsible for a few web sites of my organization.

I use Joomla! 2.5.9 for those web sites. They all are running at the same server.

I use K2 component for content managing.

I have a general website in which shows all the staff information at the 'Staff' page. Also some of those people and their contents are shown in another department's website. So, there are databases for each web site.

For example:

In the general website (let's say general.org), when I click on the 'Staff' menu item, page shows all of the people work at my organization. Also they work at different departments.

In another web site (eg: education.general.org) when I click on the 'Staff' menu item, It shows the people work at education department.

But for each web site, I have different user accounts which means a modification in one of them does not affect the other one. If the one of the education staff tries to change his profile picture on the education web site, he also has to do it on the general web site.

And sometimes one person might be working at two departments. Thus he has to edit three times of his data.

Is it possible to merge the records for all websites? In other words, I want everyone to insert/update their data on the general web site, and the other web sites will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to have one Joomla site to do this. The subdomains would have its own template/style or whatever, but would run on the same Joomla installation. The subdomains then just map to a specific menu item on the general page. That would be one way to do it.

Another way would involve coding a custom user plugin which updates the tables from the other Joomla installations after a profile was edited. If you're familiar with PHP you could probably do this yourself, otherwise you need someone with coding knowledge to do it for you.

Or you could set up Joomla to use authentification based on a LDAP database (http://docs.joomla.org/LDAP). However I'm not sure how well it works with password and profile changes.

That's about the solutions I would see.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. But the things you said are not practical. These are conceptual sayings. I need more concrete solutions. LDAP is just for logging in. It is useless for my problem.

Comment: I fear there is no other solution. If LDAP is no option and restructuring the sites is neither, that leaves you to the custom user plugin which triggers on the `onUserAfterSave` event. See http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User